# Two host name for a virtual machine - 1st name given during development release , 2nd name in production

Tags: virtual-machine

We want release VM images to customer .
After deploying VM image, customer want to have their own VM name, basically two host name is needed
1st name given during development let us call "factory name" , 2nd is "production name" given by customer.

During development applications, certificate, DNS, etc use "factory name"
after deploying VM image & change to "production name" all this become invalid

basically we want to have both name to be valid and all reference to "factory name" & "production name"  shall work interchangeably with out any issue.
we can add "factory name" & "production name" with same IP address in /etc/hosts & DNS "CNAME" .

Let us know any other things we need to take care.
Any standard procedure is there to follow VM image delivery

Comment: Any system-name basef-authentication is designed to regard a change in system name as an invalidating attack. You'll have to reinstall certificates, edit DNS, Apache, and other config files.

Answer (score 0):

No machine can have more than one hostname, but any any machine can have multiple DNS names (and that's probably what you want) pointing to the IP address the machine has.

Depending on OS, a machine can also have multiple IP adresses (on one/multiple interfaces - it's hard to see a usecase for an OS that doesn't allow at least one IP/interface), but it depends on the VM provider if that is possible (many charge for extra IPs), and it is not needed in many cases.